# Play Framework Scala, OWrites[List[A]]?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

How can I get an OWrite[List[A]] when I have a OWrites[A]? It feels it should be easy but I'm fiddling around and can't get there.

There is a OWrites.list[A] method but it returns a Writes[List[A]]..

Comment: Do you actually understand what `OWrites` is supposed to be? It is specialized version of `Writes` that you should use when you are sure you will get an `JsObject` as opposed to `JsValue` that can be anything. For lists it is natural to be stored as `JsArray` not `JsObject`.

Comment: Yes indeed, I didn't need it - thanks. I hope this question doesn't get anymore downvotes.. :/

Comment: For the record, that wasn't me who downvoted that. I think this is perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OWrites` is meant for serializing to `JsObject` specificly, as opposed to `Writes` which works for all `JsValue`s. Implementation can be found here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes.scala

```
trait Writes[-A] {
  def writes(o: A): JsValue
  ...
}

trait OWrites[-A] extends Writes[A] {
  def writes(o: A): JsObject
  ...
}
```

The idea behind it is to tell type system that your object will be serialized as `JsObject` instead of general `JsValue` that would force you to downcast.

It would be unnatural to keep a `List` in a `JsObject`, you would have to create a field inside that would hold an `JsArray` and you can do that, creating a custom instance of `OWrites` and this is why there is no `OWrites` for lists. However the obvious solution is to just use `Writes` and let your `List` be stored within a `JsArray`.